# Buffer Read from AudioRecord.read just contains zeros

Tags: java, android

I'm using AndroidRecord and can't figure out why a buffer read into by `AndroidRecord.read` contains just zeroes. No exception is triggered when I run my application on my phone.

I'm calling the constructor for AndroidRecord like this:

```
 mAudioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                RECORDING_SAMPLE_RATE, RECORDING_CHANNEL_FORMAT,
                RECORDING_AUDIO_ENCODING, numBytesToBuffer * numBytesPerElement);
```

Further up the class, here are my private fields:

```
private AudioRecord mAudioRecord = null;
private final int RECORDING_SAMPLE_RATE=44100;
private final int RECORDING_CHANNEL_FORMAT= AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private final int RECORDING_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private boolean mIsRecording;
private short[] mBuffer;
private Thread mThread = null;
private int numBytesToBuffer = 1024;
private int numBytesPerElement = 2;
```

Inside `mThread` I repeatedly call `mAudioRecord.read` inside `run`:

```
int readResult = mAudioRecord.read(mBuffer, 0, numBytesToBuffer);
if (readResult < 0) {
  Log.e("audio buffer",
        "failed to read block:" +
            ((readResult == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION)
                 ? "ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION"
                 : (readResult == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE)
                       ? "ERROR_BAD_VALUE"
                       : (readResult == AudioRecord.ERROR_DEAD_OBJECT)
                             ? "ERROR_DEAD_OBJECT"
                             : "ERROR"));
}
for (short s : mBuffer) {
  Log.v("audio buffer", "" + s);
}
```

Why does my buffer only contain zeroes?